# How to backup an iPhone when the screen is broken, the home button is broken, and it says "Unlock iPhone to use accessories?"

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup

I'm trying to backup my old and (very) broken iPhone so I can restore it on a new phone. The home button is broken, and the top half of the screen is broken (so I cannot enter my password). I also cannot access the menu you get when you swipe up, and Touch ID doesn't work. I have tried plugging it in to do a backup from iTunes, but I get the message "Unlock iPhone to use accessories" when plugging it in. I do not have "Hey Siri" enabled and I can't use the home button to activate Siri (I read about a trick to sign in using Siri). My phone is connected to WiFi and to Find My iPhone. I have access to a Mac and PC.

It is an iPhone SE model A1723.

Is there any way I can back it up still (iTunes, iCloud, or some other method) to restore it onto a new phone? If there's any more relevant info I forgot to add, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to back an iPhone up to a Mac or PC with iTunes, or to initiate an iCloud backup, without a working screen to input the lock code, unless you have used the iPhone with the same computer and iTunes before so it is already trusted.

Your best bet might be to take your phone and computer to a 3rd party Apple device service shop and ask if they can please attach a used screen with working touch for a bit so you can do the backup. They might be willing to do that for a few pieces of cheddar cheese...